# Pass an object literal to an object with a variable name inside a function

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

This is just an example:

```
var foo = "foo1";
fooFunction({
    bar: {
        foo : value
    }
});
```

The property will be named `foo` instead of `foo1`.

How can I make it be called `foo1`?

Comment: This is not valid syntax, function must have name

Comment: could you clarify what you want to do? are you trying to pass an object as parameter, and you want foo1 as a key inside bar? the fact the code is not with proper syntax regarding the function makes it a bit confusing to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It's just an example, but I'll edit it with a valid syntax

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify a dynamic property name in an object literal, you would have to add the property after the object is created.

```
var foo = "foo1";
var obj = {
    bar: {}
};
obj.bar[foo] = value;
function(obj);
```

Comment: Can I use something like `[foo]: value`? I remember seeing it somewhere some time ago

Comment: If you are only targeting the most recent browsers, sure.  Then go with Amit's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about an object literal when used as an input to a function call. The rules of object literals apply wherever it is used, including assignment, input parameters, destructing (ES2015) or any other usage I might have left out.

It is possible using ES2015 to do this with a slight change:

```
var foo = "foo1";
fooFunction({
    bar: {
        [foo] : value
    }
});
```

This is called computed property name.

Comment: I saw that some time ago somewhere, I tried it, but my IDE said the syntax was wrong, so I did not test it. And how do I know if the browser is using this specification, and which are the browsers that work with this specification? Can you update your answer with this?

Comment: @Rafael - most browsers won't naively support this today. If you want to use this reliably, use a transpiler. As for updating the answer, I don't want to. Answers are here to stay, but feature support changes every day. I don't think it makes sense that an answer won't be correct in the (potentially) near future.

Comment: what is a transpiler?

Comment: @Rafael - babeljs & traceur are the big names. Goggle it up